Regarding Invariance under modular transformations
Lets say I have a function $f(\tau)$ which we know that it is invariant under modular transformations, i.e, $f(\tau+1)=f(\tau)$,and $f(-\frac{1}{\tau})=f(\tau)$. Now let's generalize the function with a marked point $z$. Then can I conclude that if I show $f(z\to 0,\tau)$ is modular invariant, the generalized function is also modular invariant? I saw such examples with automorphic forms but can not remember the reference.
